# Java how to detect variable change

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, plugins

I have the cordova plugin and it is working. However, the while loop to wait until hashmap has something seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

```
public class MyApp extends CordovaPlugin {
  static HashMap<String,String> myProp = new HashMap<String,String>();

  protected void pluginInitialize() {
  }

  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) 
      throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("init")) {
      AppConnectionService.requestConfig(cordova.getActivity());

      init(callbackContext);

      PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT;
      PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(status);
      pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
      callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);    

      return true;      
    }
    return false;
  }

  private void init(final CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    while(myProp.isEmpty()) { 
    }

    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, myProp.get("myID"));
    result.setKeepCallback(false);
    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);         
  }

  public static boolean handleConfig (Bundle config) {
      if (config != null) {
        // Add all the entries that came in the config for the display adapter
        for (String key: config.keySet()) {            
          myProp.put(key, config.getString(key));
        }
      } else {
          Log.d("MyApp", "Failed");
      }
      return false;
  }  
}
```

So on the JavaScript part it will call `init()`, and return "myID", but the way I am waiting for the result is a busy loop:

```
while(myProp.isEmpty()) { 
}
```

Is there a more efficient and robust way to wait for the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a place to use `wait` and `notify`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306

Comment: Could you give example in my code? based on my code? Thanks

Comment: There are examples in those links. Try to adapt them in your code and post if you have problems.